# Deleted espresso test are still running

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I deleted a whole test file(let's call it `Test.java`) from my `androidTest` folder and the tests in the `Test.java` are still running when I right click the `androidTest` folder and select "Run Tests in com". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Android Studios:
1)Build -> Clean Project 
2)Build -> Rebuild Project

After this try to run your test sets and check if there is anymore "old" deleted ones running.

Answer (score 0):

If you ran this deleted test individually at some point, it may be stored in your configurations. Click the drop down next to the play button > Edit Configurations and see if any old tests are lingering there.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the apk(s) fixed it for me.

1. I also tried clean, which i thought would wipe out the old apks, but that didn't work.
2. I tried deleting all items in Edit Configurations and that didn't work.